# PID and incremental aproach

Tags: linux, kernel, process

Suppose I have 10 process such as :

```
process p0 with PID 1.
process p1 with PID 2.
process p2 with PID 3.
process p3 with PID 4.
process p4 with PID 5.
process p5 with PID 6.
process p6 with PID 7.
process p7 with PID 8.
process p8 with PID 9.
process p9 with PID 10.
```

When I kill a process, such as :

```
kill 7
```

and process p6 is killed successfully, between process p5 and p7 is empty, when I run p10 as a process, kernel assigns PID 11 to p10.

Question is why kernel (linux and freebsd) assigns a incremental PID instead of assigning PID 7 to process p11?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PIDs aren’t reused as soon as they’re freed because doing so results in races, and ultimately, bugs which can sometimes be used to evade security restrictions (see [these examples of Android security bugs caused by PID races](https://lwn.net/ml/linux-kernel/CAG48ez2gb94SqS30Ai4+VBHhnzBp5Po9_u00nMrvUW6Wqq6hPA@mail.gmail.com/)).

If PIDs are reused, then processes which hold a PID for whatever reason (*e.g.*, to send a signal to some other process) might not realise immediately that the process they intend to communicate with has exited. Once the PID is recycled, it’s difficult to reliably detect that the process using it has changed. Delaying this reuse makes races less likely (albeit not impossible). Other approaches include raising the maximum PID (as done *e.g.* on Fedora — see `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max`), but again that only reduces the likelihood.

[The Linux kernel recently added `pidfd`s](https://lwn.net/Articles/784831/) to provide a reliable way of reasoning about processes and their PIDs.